# placing transition data on stacked bars with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to recreate [this graph](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/hflutt/reimagining_the_los_angeles_city_budget_oc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) in R but I can't manage to have the transition data displayed in red stacked bars. I also don't know how to show the bar that decreases in value in another color as in the graph of the link.

Here's a sample code to work from:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(31,2,4,25,6,7,20,9,10,15,12,13,10,15,16,5,18,19), 
                frame=c(rep('a',3), rep('b',3), rep('c',3), rep('d',3), rep('e',3), rep('f',3)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=values, fill=group)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = values), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) +
  transition_manual(frame) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to get this kind of animation. Instead of using some kind of stacked bar chart I two `geom_col` layers to achieve the desired result.

The first `geom_col` plots the `values` over time, whereby the fill is based on whether the values increase or decrease compared to the base value. The second `geom_col` plots the `values` over time, whereby the fill is based on whether the values increase or decrease compared to the base value.

The seocnd `geom_col` simply plots the base `values` whereby in that case I use the `alpha` aes to get the transparency based on whether the values increase or decrease compared to the base value.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), values=c(31,2,4,25,6,7,20,9,10,15,12,13,10,15,16,5,18,19), 
                 frame=c(rep('a',3), rep('b',3), rep('c',3), rep('d',3), rep('e',3), rep('f',3)))

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(base = values[frame == "a"],
         diff = values - base) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(df1, aes(x=group)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_col(aes(y=values, fill = diff > 0), position = "identity") +
  geom_col(aes(y=base, alpha = diff > 0), fill = "blue", position = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1, "FALSE" = .2)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=values, label = values), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) +
  transition_manual(frame) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> nframes and fps adjusted to match transition
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for. I had no idea one can define two different geom_cols. Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are missing information in your data (df) to have a stacked bar chart. I created a column `frac` which contains a multiplier for your `values` column. In this simple example we will plot a stacked bar chart with a bar for each group where values and values*frac are stacked. Is this what you are after?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"), 
                 values= c(31,2,4,25,6,7,20,9,10,15,12,13,10,15,16,5,18,19), 
                 frac = c(1, 1, 1, 1.1, 0.9, 0.8, 1.2, 0.8, 0.7, 1.2, 0.7, 0.6, 1.3, 0.6, 0.5, 1.4, 0.5, 0.4),
                 frame=c(rep('a',3), rep('b',3), rep('c',3), rep('d',3), rep('e',3), rep('f',3)))


df <- df %>%
  mutate(values2 = values * frac) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("values"),
               names_to = "values", 
               values_to = "data")
  

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = data)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = values)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = values), vjust = -0.3, size = 3.5) +
  transition_manual(frame) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. While Stefan's answer is closer to what I wanted, this approach also works.